# How to deploy an web application in netbeans (prod / test)

Tags: apache, maven, tomcat, ant, build

I have create an web app in Netbeans.
My project contains this architecture:

```
WebApplication
--web pages
----meta-inf
----web-inf
----index.html
--Source Packages
-----test
-------TestEnv.java
--Librairies
----JDK 1.8
----Apache Tomcat 8.0.27.0
----Configuration files
-------Manifest.mf
-------context.xml 
-------web-fragment.xml
-------web-fragment.xml
```

How can I test if I am in production or test.
If It's a production , I will call a prod.properties 
If It's a test, I will call test.properties
I already lookup some post like environment variable in tomcat server.xml but It's not recognized :(
I don't want to use maven also.
I am looking a solution based on a read of xml file.
If in the xml file prod is equal to true so It's in production so I call prod.properties.

Have you got an idea of this xml file .(similar to ant ?)
Thanks

Comment: And reading a System variable that just exists in development environment or with different values for production and development environment ?

Comment: @jorge I just want to read a xml file and choose the correct database